# Why is my v4 OData feed working in powerbi desktop but not in excel 2016. Error says invalid metadata

Tags: .net, odata, powerquery

I have created a v4 odata service, which I have tested and confirmed to be working in Power BI desktop.

However, it isn't working in Excel 2016 Power Query

I've tried everything i can think of

The error message I get is:

DataSource.Error: OData: The feed's metadata document appears to be invalid.
Details:
    DataSourceKind=OData
    DataSourcePath=http://196.45.48.111/

It is very strange, because the metadata looks fine, and it works properly on power bi desktop

Any help would be appreciated, as i have been stuck on this problem for days

You can find my odata service at http://196.45.48.111/. You need to use basic authentication to access it.

Username: test
Password: test

Note: this test account only allows you to view the service document and metadata. You can't actually run any queries

Thanks in advance for your help

Comment: Have you installed the latest update for Excel 2016? If not, does it work after the update?

Comment: Hi @Alejandro, Thank you for your reply. It did work after the update. Unfortunately, now, I'm getting an error saying that power query does not support clr type 'Microsoft.OData.Edm.Library.Date'. Any idea when this may be supported, because my clients expect to be able to consume this feed from Excel. BTW, it works fine in Power BI. Thanks for your help

Comment: That issue will be fixed in one of the next Excel updates.